# Add, delete row and rebind large no of data

Tags: asp.net, sql, jquery

In my application I am using `Json` to bind data from `sql` as (bind data as per scroll) approach.

It is working fine but I when I delete or add new data , I want that row should be updated without loading all list. As I have seen in facebook we have loaded number of data by page scrolling , now when we add new post or delete any post, all data doesn't reload, only one row is (delete/added)to list.

How I can achieve this effect?

I am using this link  code :
http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Load-data-while-Scrolling-Page-down-with-jQuery-AJAX-and-ASPNet.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality you want to achive can be done using `Jquery Ajax`. Please find below detailed information on `Update records` in grid view

[Update records in Grid View using Jquery Ajax](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/44052-Update-Delete-GridView-using-JQuery-without-page-post-back.aspx)

And Simillar implementation on `Delete Records`

[Delete records in Grid View using Jquery Ajax](http://forums.asp.net/t/1893481.aspx/1)

Hope this helps.

**Edit**

One of simillar implementation on delete records from grid.

http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1535-delete-row-from-gridview-and-database-using.aspx

Comment: Thanks For Posting , It helped me . Now I am able to delete row from sql. But I am not getting updated data after row deletion. I don;t know how to remove that row from binded row. As I am binding row on page scroll ,on page scrolling new data is added to binded  data. You can see how data is added on my posted link

Comment: If you are deleting from SQL means it will never appear on screen again. And in front end  `$(row).remove();` this code does the magic of removing the selected row.

Comment: Updated my response check the new link.

Comment: I am showing data in nested table  , that mean  each table has  different id . I want to pass this table id to   function RemoveRow(id){ $(".id").slideUp(400, function () { $(".id").remove();}).slideDown(400);} . On this function I am passing table id, my table is dynamic (binding through database) . Problem is how I can get this Id in ajax , on above I tried but it's not working . When I do with fixed Class it is working correctly.

Comment: Can you post some of HTML code of your nested grid may be i can help identifying the dyanmic table id.

Comment: Thanks Pratik alot, you really helped me ,and I fix the problem.